# Проблема с преобразованием символов с кнопок в единую переменную

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пишу игру будучи абсолютным новичком. Для написания использую Js / Jquery.

Сейчас нахожусь на завершающей стадии

Суть проблемы, имеется шесть кнопок с различными буквами, при нажатии на которых в переменную должно заносится значение с кнопки.

```
$( "#start" ).on('click', function(nach) {
var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * words.length );
var shuffledWord = words[rand].shuffle();
for (var k = 0; k < shuffledWord.length; k++ ) {
$('#Letter1').text(shuffledWord[k]);  
$('#Letter2').text(shuffledWord[k-1]);  
$('#Letter3').text(shuffledWord[k-2]);  
$('#Letter4').text(shuffledWord[k-3]);  
$('#Letter5').text(shuffledWord[k-4]);  
$('#Letter6').text(shuffledWord[k-5]);
}
$( "#start" ).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Это код присваивания кнопке рандомного значения из массива, с ним проблем нет.

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку в переменную не заносится ничего, то есть она как была пустой, так пустой и остается, вот код переменной

```
newword += shuffledWord[k]; //при нажатии на первую кнопку
newword += shuffledWord[k-1]; // при нажатии на вторую и т.д
```

Прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос, только начинаю. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Проблема решена, большое спасибо Елене за помощь !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь код бы посмотреть.
Что в этот момент в переменной k? Присвоение происходит после того, как цикл прошёл и k == shuffledWord.length?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huRTj/2/ 

Здесь весь проект, изменение переменной сделано в самом начале JS-кода, а то, что я вывесил, в самом конце. Код не адаптирован, я только учусь :)

Comment: вообще-то на момент обработки события даже shuffledWord не определён

Comment: Разве ? Изначально игр начинается с нажатия кнопки старт, при котором каждой букве присуждается значение, получается, что при передвижении значение у кнопки уже имеется ? Или что-то я не понял ?

Comment: если писать в таком духе, как сейчас, букву можно и брать с кнопки тем же методом .text()

Comment: игра начинается с нажатия кнопки #start, но до нажатия уже определены обработчики для кнопок с буквами, и вот на момент, когда эти обработчики задаются, кнопка #start ещё не нажата, а shuffledWord определяется только после нажатия #start.

Comment: То есть newword += Letter1.text(shuffledWord[k]);  ?

Comment: нет. $( "#Letter1" ).click(function(){ newword += $(this).text() }

Comment: Теперь дошло в чем была проблема, по сути стоит просто-напросто спрятать обрабочиков под кнопку ?